# Understanding " Flagged Posts for [UserName]"

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

I need help in interpreting my "Flagged Posts" page:

I first thought, this was only a list of the flags I raised myself, but there is one entry about "[Why are memory locations assigned garbage values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704710/why-are-memory-locations-assigned-garbage-values/29705672#29705672)?" that is marked as `flagged as spam helpful`.

I can't remember raising a flag on that question (certainly not about being spam) but - aside from posting an actual answer - I did write a comment that linked to a piece of code from me on codereview, which probably could be seen as spam (It was somewhat related but clearly not an answer).

Now my questions are:

1. Am I right with my assumption, that this is an entry about my comment being flagged as spam?
2. Does the `helpful` part mean that someone thought that this flag (and not the comment) was helpful?
3. If so, why wasn't the comment deleted and why didn't I get a message about one of my posts having been (correctly?) flagged?
4. Do you think that post is SPAM and I should delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You flagged an answer to that question as spam. You can't see the answer there anymore because it's since been deleted, hence why your flag was marked as helpful - it resulted in blatant spam being deleted.

Comment: Ah, of course - I completely forgot about that. Thanks for the quick clarification.